# Is it possible to use cql to query collections in a row?

Tags: cassandra, cql

Assuming you have movies as a row, and a list of categories, i.e.

```
create table movie(
    uuid timeuuid,
    name text,
    category list<text>
    primary key (uuid)
);

insert into movie (uuid,name,category) values(now(), 'my movie', ['romance','comedy']);
insert into movie (uuid,name,category) values(now(), 'other movie', ['action','comedy']);
```

Is it possible to efficiently do something like:

```
select * from movie where category='comedy'
select * from movie where category='comedy' and category='action'
```

This use case is the most common query against our MySQL database.

Comment: This is something I need to work out as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[As of cassandra 2.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4511), yes it is:

```
create table cinema.movie(
    id timeuuid,
    name text,
    category list<text>, 
    primary key (id)
);

CREATE index ON cinema.movie (category);
INSERT INTO cinema.movie (id, name, category) VALUES (now(), 'my movie', ['romance','comedy']);
SELECT * FROM cinema.movie WHERE category CONTAINS 'romance';


 uuid                                 | category               | name
--------------------------------------+------------------------+----------
 b9e0d7f0-995f-11e3-b11c-c5d4ddc8930a | ['romance', 'comed`y'] | my movie

(1 rows)
```

P.S. you have errors in your queries, you are missing a `,` in your create table statement after category's declaration and you cant use the `now()` function on UUID, you are looking for the TIMEUUID type instead.

Bare in mind that performance wont be magnificent (how's that for quantitative) when it come's to using these collections, it might be better to create a separate table for this sort of thing.

Comment: Yep, perhaps I should have been a little clearer, this is the _primary_ use case of the system, it needs to be fast. Isn't 2.1 still in beta anyway? This however probably does answer my question, ie, "there's no way to do this but create a special index table"?

Comment: This is useful information! But I'm not sure a beta product is the correct answer :D

Comment: Cassandra secondary indexes are useful, but are usually not valid to use for the "primary use case" of a system.  As secondary indexes do not scale out, as they use a scatter/gather algorithm.  If this is a primary use case you should denormalize the query into a 2nd table.

Comment: @Jacob The question didn't mention whether the cluster would be used as a production cluster, it simply asked if it's possible, which it is, however your comment does hold value, picking beta products for production is risky.